# REST API and real time event notification

Tags: rest

I am exploring `REST API`, I want to know is there a way in `REST` to have `Real time event notification` to the client. I understand that `REST` is `STATELESS protocol`. One way to do this is to have client register for the interested events and `poll` for the same using some `rest api`. Is there any other way to do the say without using `poll`

Answer (score 0):

You should try Atmosphere framework if you are trying this using Java.

It supports Jersey REST and server push.